# can we make applications in html\javascript for android?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I want to learn android application development.But the problem is I just have the knowledge of HTML,Javascript, css and ajax but no idea about java technology.

So is it possible to make android apps using Html or js.

If anyone have any idea about this then please suggest me.

Thanks in advance!

Arvind Thakur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) to develop applications in HTML5, javascript that will work in various smartphone platforms.

In fact you don't need to rely on a framework. With a minimum of Java plumbing you can set up a WebView activity. There you can use html, css and javascript. Interaction with Java code is also possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I go with phonegap.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.phonegap.com/

> PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app stores. PhoneGap leverages web technologies developers already know best... HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: http://www.quickconnectfamily.org/ here is another one (that I don't know too much about)

Answer (score 2):

See The [titanium framework](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/). but note that apps like this are very limmiting to what you can achieve and build. but as a simple web page like functionality and rapid development its great. Also with this your app will be really easely portable to iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my tiny collection of cross-platform frameworks: http://www.delicious.com/masterik/cross+platform+mobile-development

Most of them are based on html/css/javascript.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.delicious.com/masterik/cross+platform+mobile-development 
Most of them are based on html/css/javascript.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.